# Каким другим способом можно получить последний элемент массива из ответа в виде json-массива?

Tags: php, json

Столкнулся с проблемой.
Работаю с Яндекс api и при очередном запросе получаю ответ в виде json-массива. Я его декодирую и с помощью `end()` считываю последние значения. Но вот незадача: иногда, я пока не знаю в чем дело вылазит ошибка:

> `end()` expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in

Каким другим способом можно получить последний элемент массива?

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [StatusReport] => Done [ReportID] => 613936 ) [1] => Array ( [ReportID] => 613939 [StatusReport] => Done ) [2] => Array ( [ReportID] => 613940 [StatusReport] => Done ) [3] => Array ( [ReportID] => 613941 [StatusReport] => Done ) [4] => Array ( [StatusReport] => Done [ReportID] => 613944 ) [5] => Array ) )
```

Мой код:

```
 $result3 = curl_exec($ch); //получил ответ от сервера
curl_close($ch);
$result3 = json_decode($result3, true);
$last_element = end($result3['data']);
$last_report_id = $last_element['ReportID']; //айдишник последнего запроса
$last_status_report = $last_element['StatusReport'];//статус последнего запрос
```

Comment: Ваша ошибка означает, что в тело функции попал аргумент, который не является массивом)

Возможно там, что то другое приходит, попробуйте отловить

Comment: отловить? а как? подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: сохраните содержимое $result3 в файл и смотрите) Може воспользоваться функцией file_put_contents

Comment: спасибо! крутая штука. и не знал о такой

Answer (score 1):

У Вас `$result3['data']` равен `null`. Почему? Смотрите сами

```
$response = curl_exec($ch); //получил ответ от сервера
curl_close($ch);
if ($response === false)
  die("Content not load");
$result3 = json_decode($response, true);
if (!isset($result3))
  die("JSON decode error. " . $response);
if (!isset($result3['data']))
  die("Element 'data' not found. " . $response);
$last_element = end($result3['data']);
```

Comment: `isset(['data']` ?

Comment: @teran Промахнулся

Answer (score 0):

При определенных обстоятельствах, в вашу функцию end передается значение null вместо массива. Это происходит потому, что функция json_decode() возвращает null. Это может быть связано либо с проблемой в структуре json (синтаксические ошибки и тп.), либо вы вообще не смогли получить json от сервера при curl запросе. Попробуйте провести отладку, чтобы локализовать проблему.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как произвести отладку

Comment: Самый простой вариант - выводить на экран значение $result3 после получение ответа от curl (приходящий json) и после выполнения функции json_decode() (результат парсинга) с помощью var_dump(). Если на экран выводить нельзя, можно сохранять результаты в текстовый файл. Вообще, хорошим подходом для отладки было бы использование xdebug: https://habrahabr.ru/post/250323/

Comment: Сергей! спасибо большое!